# Nth root of a being greater than 1 when a is greater than 1

Tags: real-analysis

In a part of a bigger proof, we need to prove that when $a>1$ then $\sqrt[n]{a}>1$. We were told to do it using the binomial theorem, so I tried to do it like this. If $a>1$ then $a=1+δ$ where $δ>0$. So then an=(1+δ)n>nδ. But then I got stuck, where do I go from here? Why does the Binomial theorem help here? Isn't it easier to prove this by contradiction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $b:=\sqrt[n]{a}$. Write $b=1+\delta$, you need to show that $\delta>0$.

By assumption $b^n = a>1$. Now use the binomial Theorem to calculate $b^n=(1+\delta)^n$

Comment: I also agree that it is easier to prove this by contradiction... but this is my opinion I guess some would not agree.

Answer (score 1):

It is much easier to apply the contrapositive below to $b=\sqrt[n]{a}$:

> If $0< b \le 1$, then $0< b^n \le 1$

This follows directly by induction on $n$.